# Sitecode URL to Media file

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a function that automatically creates PDF files in the sitecore Media Library. I want to display a link on another webpage to download or view this PDF.

```
Sitecore.Data.Database context= Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem item = (Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem)context.GetItem("/sitecore/Media Library/Requests/"+ddlRequests.SelectedValue+".pdf");
```

To get the item link I use the following line. This line won't execute appearently.

```
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item);
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the value of ddlRequests.SelectedValue ?

Comment: Its a unique number that is also the name of the pdf. Example "36"+".pdf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code should work just fine without the `.pdf` in the query. Select one of the pdf files in Media Library and on the `content` tab check what is the value of `Item Path` property. This is what you should use in the query (so most probably without `.pdf`):

```
Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem item = (Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem)db.GetItem("/sitecore/Media Library/Requests/" + ddlRequests.SelectedValue);
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! The code works now but the URL does not though. When I Click it I am redirected to an errorpage. Do I need to publish the item first or something? My code only adds it to the Media Library, not sure if there's anything else I should do before its visible.

Comment: Yes, media items from Media Library are just kind of sitecore items - they have to be published as well. What is the link that is generated by the code? Does it start with "/"?

Comment: the file is created under /sitecore/Media Library/Requests

Comment: And what is the link generated by the code Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item); ?

Comment: Have you published both 'Request' media folder and the file itself?

Comment: I have manually published the folder. The file itself is created programatically. Not sure if its being published. Guess not..

edit: I have tried to publish the item manually and now it works. It seems I will have to find a way to do this programatically. Thank you for your valuable help!